# With Spring-Boot auto-configured JavaMailSender, how to support encrypted (username/password) properties using Jasypt library?

Tags: spring-boot, annotations, jasypt, mail-sender

JavaMailSender is being auto configured in my Spring Boot application. How can I use annotations to allow encrypted values in my properties file for the properties "spring.mail.username"and "spring.mail.password" 
using the Jasypt library? please help.

```
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class SimpleMailController {

@Autowired
private JavaMailSender sender;
```

Comment: Have you tried reading https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-jasypt

Comment: I read it but it did not help. I was able to solve by adding @EnableEncryptableProperties to my Application class. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear you have resolved your problem. You could consider adding your comment as an answer.

Comment: Thanks @AlexB I have added the answer to this particular question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to crack it.

1. Add the annotation @EnableEncryptableProperties to my Application class.
2. Add jasypt spring boot starter dependency in gradle script -

> compile('com.github.ulisesbocchio:jasypt-spring-boot-starter:2.0.0')

All the properties used in my application now support encrypted values by default.

Comment: Your answer seems to be missing something.  Don't you also need to specify the property file with "@EncryptablePropertySources({@EncryptablePropertySource("classpath:encrypted.properties")})"?  Even when I do this, JavaMailSender doesn't get the password.  Did you also set a system environment variable for jasypt.encryptor.password?  Thanks!

Comment: I did not need to use the annotation @EncryptablePropertySources in my application. The property jasypt.encryptor.password should ideally be passed as a runtime variable. For testing purpose, add it in the same properties file you want to encrypt.

Comment: I would like to add one more observation. The above solution did not work when jasypt version was 3.0.3. When I downgraded to 2.0.0 the solution worked.
Refer to comments <https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot/issues/154>